# iOS: why my active viewcontroller (self) takes the address of the singleton (sharedInstance) when download a video with downloadTask?

Tags: ios, swift, download, singleton, nsurlsession

When I start the application, I would like to get the **active** app that works normally is the interaction of the user. I would like secondly that in **background**, the application check if there is process to do with old videos precedently added by the user and has not been processed.
For this, I use the current active controller (**self**) and the (**sharedInstance**) singleton.
My problem is that the address of self, the active view, takes the address of the singleton when I try to download a video in the "active mode", I don't understand why...
For example, when I use the application normally, the address is Printing description of self: 0x155d5b3a0

When I am in the urlSession(URLSession, didFinishDownloadingTo location:) function, my address is the one of the singleton 0x155e3e890

Main class:

```
@objcMembers class ViewControllerCamBox: UIViewController,URLSessionDelegate,URLSessionDownloadDelegate,FormViewViewControllerDelegate {
        static let sharedInstance = ViewControllerCamBox()
    ...

    }

    func stopVideo
    {
        ...
        self.url = fileUrls![0]
        self.downloadVideo(urlStr: self.url)
        ...
    }

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, did

WriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {

                if totalBytesExpectedToWrite > 0 {

                    if let onProgress = onProgress {
                        calculateProgress(session: session, completionHandler: onProgress)
                    }
                    let progress = Float(totalBytesWritten) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        if (self.progressLabel != nil && self.progressBar != nil)
                        {
                        self.progressBar.isHidden = false
                        self.progressBar.progress = Double(progress)
                        self.progressLabel.text = "Téléchargement en cours..."
                        self.progressLabel.isHidden = false
                    }
                }
                debugPrint("Progress \(downloadTask) \(progress)")
            }
        }

        func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
            debugPrint("Download finished: \(location)")

        let nameVideo = self.code_prospect_unique + "_video.MOV"
//MY PROBLEM => self has the sharedInstance address and not the self address of the current active viewcontroller.

        ...
        }

func downloadVideo(urlStr:String)
{
    //self.id = get id from query
    let url = URL(string: urlStr)!
    self.dataTask = self.activate().downloadTask(with: url)
    self.dataTask?.resume()
}
```

Function to launch to check if there is video to send:

```
func checkGeneral()
    {
        //check download = 0e
        let query = "SELECT ID, MAIL, URL, CODE_PROSPECT_UNIQUE FROM VIDEO WHERE DOWNLOAD = 0"
        LocalDatabase.sharedInstance.methodToSelectData(query, completion: { (result) in
            if (result.count > 0)
            {
                let viewControllerCamBox = ViewControllerCamBox.sharedInstance
                if let resultFound = result[0] as? [String: Any] {
                    guard !resultFound.keys.contains("ErrorMessage")
                        else {return}
                    let id = resultFound["ID"] as! NSNumber
                    let url = resultFound["URL"] as! String
                    let code_prospect_unique = resultFound["CODE_PROSPECT_UNIQUE"] as! String
                    viewControllerCamBox.id = id.stringValue
                    viewControllerCamBox.code_prospect_unique = code_prospect_unique
                    viewControllerCamBox.downloadVideo(urlStr: url)
                    print("Data selected successfully: code prospect unique:\(String(describing: viewControllerCamBox.code_prospect_unique))")
                }

                //each rows send
                //check resized = 0

                //check upload = 0

            }
            else
            {
                print("Fail while data selection:  code prospect unique:\(self.code_prospect_unique)")
            }
        })

    }
```

Is there something bad?
I just would like to use the singleton in background and the active view for the normal use for the user.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would not recommend this this notion of a static instance of a view controller that you use for background network tasks. Just like you have a separate object controlling your database interaction, have another object that controls your network interaction. Pull all of this network stuff out of your (massive) view controller. Then your background session and view controller can interact with this network object...

Comment: If you are using background `URLSessionConfiguration` (your use of the term “background” was a bit ambiguous), make sure you’re not dealing with downloads initiated from prior run. Debugging background sessions can get super confusing where downloads initiated from one iteration can be completed during some subsequent debugging session. It can get incredibly confusing if you’re not careful. We’re not used to one debugging session affecting a subsequent one. I often uninstall and reinstall app when debugging this sort of stuff.

Comment: You ask how “why my active viewcontroller (self) takes the address of the singleton (sharedInstance) when download a video with downloadTask?” ... The short answer is that it doesn’t. It can’t. You must have accidentally started the download task from your shared instance. You might want to share how you’re instantiating your `URLSession` and settling its `delegate`. But these instances just can’t “take the address” of the other. This question is very unclear.